# Accessing characters within string literals using [] or {}

Tags: php

[Strings chapter of PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) has a note:

> PHP 5.5 added support for accessing characters within string literals
>   using [] or {}.

What does that note particularly mean?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important note there is "string **literals**".

PHP could use `{}` in place of `[]` for string variable access since forever. What's new in PHP 5.5 is that it works on literal *values*:

```
 print "abcde"[3];
```

And yes, that's seldomly needed.

Comment: in example will print 4

Comment: Changed it to letters; for clarity.

Comment: That's what I thought. What about curly braces? PHP throws parse error.

Comment: I have PHP 5.5.9 and next line parsed with error:
**print "abcde"{3};**

Comment: So, umm, the manual is actually lying. Only works with `[0]` then. (The PHP development model is lately centered around inconsistency, rushing changes, or breaking backwards compatibility.)

Comment: Only reference is http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.new-features.php, and it seems `{}` was forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug or a mistake in the manual.